# Overlapping semi-transparent elements?

Tags: transparency

I want the area overlapped to be of the same opacity of the rest.  This is my code in CSS that creates an overlapped area that is darker than the rest:

```
.title {
    width: 497px;
    height: 252px;
    font-family:'Bebas';
    text-align:right;

}
.title span {
    line-height:54px;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 72px;
    background:rgba(193,193,193,.3);
    color: white;
    padding:3px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="title">
    <span>This is where</span><br>
    <span>the content goes</span>
</div>
```

So, how do I go about making the overlapped area the same opacity without using an image?